# How to take log of a unit with dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

I have a temperature variable with Kelvin units. I need to take `log10` of it with `np.log10`, but it does not work if a number has dimensions. What is the easiest way to remove dimensions from the variable so I can take a log of it?

## Example

```
import astropy.units as u
import numpy as np

temp = 6000 * u.K
np.log10(temp)
```

Shows the error message:

> ```
> UnitTypeError: Can only apply 'log10' function to dimensionless quantities
> ```

Comment: have you tried temp.value..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either drop dimension with `.value`:

```
>>> np.log10(temp.value)
3.7781512503836434
```

Or divide by `u.K` to make it dimensionless:

```
>>> np.log10(temp / u.K)
<Quantity 3.7781512503836434>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the actual value without units using [**`to_value()`**](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.units.Quantity.html#astropy.units.Quantity.to_value)

> Signature: `to_value(unit=None, equivalencies=[])`

```
In [33]: temp.to_value()
Out[33]: 6000.0

In [34]: np.log10(temp.to_value())
Out[34]: 3.7781512503836439
```

This also gives the flexibility to change the units if it's needed at some point!