# Using Astropy to make an array dimensionless

Tags: python, astropy

I have an array, and I want to make it dimensionless so I can use

```
np.log()
```

However, following the guide in the Units and Quantities documentation for astropy does not seem to work.
This is the code I written so far:

```
#Calculating luminosity of a source (units Jy/Mpc^2)
luminosity = 4*pi*Total_flux*dl*dl*((1.+z)**(alpha-1.))

#using astropy to convert the units from JyMpc2 to W/Hz
lum_in_W = luminosity.to(u.Watt/u.Hertz)

#making the quantity dimensionless
lum_dimensionless = lum_in_W*u.dimensionless_unscaled

#checking to see the dimension
test = lum_dimensionless.unit
print(test)
```

The output of this is

> W / Hz

and when I try to take the log

```
log_lum = np.log(lum_dimensionless)
```

I still get this error

> UnitTypeError: Can only apply 'log' function to dimensionless quantities

Any help or hints appreciated, thanks for your time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Great job posing this question. Is `lum_in_W` also dimensionless? At least in the line that you're defining `lum_dimensionless`.

Comment: No, `lum_in_W` is in units of Watts per Hertz. I'm trying to make it dimensionless through applying `*u.dimensionless_unscaled`

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here:

```
 lum_dimensionless = lum_in_W.to_value()
```

returns the dimensionless value.
Should have found this before posting, but I suppose you can get tunnel vision sometimes into trying to get a specific line to work, especially when you are convinced it must be the correct solution--my apologies for that!

Here is the link to the answer:

[How to take log of a unit with dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470823/how-to-take-log-of-a-unit-with-dimensions)

Comment: Nice job finding the answer! However for obvious reasons this makes the question a duplicate. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯